# Spring application unable to access kafka running in kubernetes minikube

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I used `bitnami/kafka` to deploy kafka on minikube. A describe of the pod `kafka-0` looks says that server address is:

```
KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:INTERNAL://$(MY_POD_NAME).kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9093,CLIENT://$(MY_POD_NAME).kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

My kafka address is set like so in Spring config properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=["kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092"]
```

But when I try to send a message I get the following error:

```
Failed to construct kafka producer] with root cause:
  org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: 
    Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: ["kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092"]
```

Note that this works when I run kafka locally and set the bootstrap-servers address to `localhost:9092`

How do I fix this error? What is the correct kafka URL to use and where do I find it? thanks

Comment: You need to use a CSV value in the spring properties, not `[]` list. Also, there should possibly be a `kafka` service / ClusterIP that you should be using for bootstrapping **instead of** individual pod addresses... You may also be interested in https://strimzi.io

Answer (score 0):

Minikube network is different to the host network, you need a bridge.
The advertised listener is in the minikube realm, not findable from the host.
You could setup a service and an ingress in minikube pointing to your kafka, setup your hosts file to the ip address of the ingress and the hostname advertised.

Answer (score -1):

`spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` needs valid server hostnames along with port number as comma-separated

```
hostname-1:port,hostname-2:port
```

`["kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092"]` is not looking like one!

Comment: `localhost` won't work inside a kubernetes pod, plus Kafka is not running on port 8080... `kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local` is a DNS hostname... `:9092` is a port. Why would that not work?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Because he is using enclosing the server name and port in [""] which is not a valid pattern as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: Well, in Spring's YAML properties, `["host:port", "host:port"]` actually is valid

Comment: Good point, I didn't thought of that.